# SharePoint 2010 - workflow to copy files from one sharepoint farm to another

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Seemingly simple requirement.  We have two SharePoint web applications hosted on the same server.  Site A is used internally and is thought of as hosting the source documents.  Site B is accessed by external suppliers.
I would like to have SharePoint automagically copy new documents from a doc library in Site A to a doc library on Site B.  It would need to preserve metadata.  The process would need to "fire" each time a new document was uploaded into the document library in Site A.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for workflow solution in this case?

Go for Item Added event receiver for that document library.
Use managed client object to copy the document to library in another farm.

Comment: I'm not against that method but am also not familiar with it.  Can you elaborate a little more on what is required to do that?

Comment: You will have to write custom code in event receiver in visual studio if you are familier with the object model of sharepoint.

Comment: 1. create sharepoint project in vs. 2. Add item added event receiver to it. 3. Write code to copy the document of current item to another farm using client object model